# Transactions with Guice and JDBC - Solution discussion

Tags: jdbc, transactions, guice, transactionmanager

In my application, I need to use pure JDBC together with Guice. However, Guice doesn't provide any built-in support to manage transactions. guice-persist only provides support based on JPA, which I cannot use.

so I tried to implement a simple solution to manage transactions with Guice and JDBC. here is the first version:

1. use TransactionHolder to store the transaction per thread.

   public class JdbcTransactionHolder {

   ```
   private static ThreadLocal<JdbcTransaction> currentTransaction = new ThreadLocal<JdbcTransaction>();

   public static void setCurrentTransaction(JdbcTransaction transaction) {
       currentTransaction.set(transaction);
   }

   public static JdbcTransaction getCurrentTransaction() {
       return currentTransaction.get();
   }

   public static void removeCurrentTransaction() {
       currentTransaction.remove();
   }
   ```

   }
2. implements a transaction manager for JDBC, for now only begin(), getTransaction(), commit() and rollback() method:

   public class JdbcTransactionManager implements TransactionManager {

   ```
   @Inject
   private DataSource dataSource;

   @Override
   public void begin() throws NotSupportedException, SystemException {
       logger.debug("Start the transaction");
       try {
           JdbcTransaction tran = JdbcTransactionHolder.getCurrentTransaction();
           Connection conn = null;
           if(tran == null) {
               conn = dataSource.getConnection();
           }
           else {
               conn = tran.getConnection();
           }

           // We have to put the connection in the holder so that we can get later
           // from the holder and use it in the same thread
           logger.debug("Save the transaction for thread: {}.", Thread.currentThread());
           JdbcTransactionHolder.setCurrentTransaction(new JdbcTransaction(conn));
       } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }

   }

   @Override
   public void commit() throws RollbackException, HeuristicMixedException,
           HeuristicRollbackException, SecurityException,
           IllegalStateException, SystemException {
       logger.debug("Commit the transaction");
       try {
           logger.debug("Get the connection for thread: {}.", Thread.currentThread());
           Transaction transaction = JdbcTransactionHolder.getCurrentTransaction();
           transaction.commit();

       }
       catch(Exception e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
       finally {
           JdbcTransactionHolder.removeCurrentTransaction();
       }
   }

   @Override
   public Transaction getTransaction() throws SystemException {
       logger.debug("Get transaction.");
       final JdbcTransaction tran = JdbcTransactionHolder.getCurrentTransaction();
       if(tran == null) {
           throw new DBException("No transaction is availble. TransactionManager.begin() is probably not yet called.");
       }

       return tran;
   }

   @Override
   public void rollback() throws IllegalStateException, SecurityException,
           SystemException {
       logger.debug("Rollback the transaction");

       try {
           logger.debug("Get the transaction for thread: {}.", Thread.currentThread());
           Transaction conn = JdbcTransactionHolder.getCurrentTransaction();
           conn.commit();
       }
       catch(Exception e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
       finally {
           JdbcTransactionHolder.removeCurrentTransaction();
       }
   }
   ```

   }
3. implement a wrapper for DataSource which can get the current connection from the transaction holder if a transaction has been started:

   public class JdbcDataSource implements DataSource {

   ```
   private final static org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JdbcDataSource.class);

   private DataSource dataSource;

   public JdbcDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
       this.dataSource = dataSource;
   }

   @Override
   public PrintWriter getLogWriter() throws SQLException {
       return dataSource.getLogWriter();
   }

   @Override
   public int getLoginTimeout() throws SQLException {

       return dataSource.getLoginTimeout();
   }

   @Override
   public Logger getParentLogger() throws SQLFeatureNotSupportedException {

       return dataSource.getParentLogger();
   }

   @Override
   public void setLogWriter(PrintWriter out) throws SQLException {
       this.dataSource.setLogWriter(out);
   }

   @Override
   public void setLoginTimeout(int seconds) throws SQLException {
       this.dataSource.setLoginTimeout(seconds);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isWrapperFor(Class<?> arg0) throws SQLException {
       return this.isWrapperFor(arg0);
   }

   @Override
   public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> iface) throws SQLException {

       return this.unwrap(iface);
   }

   @Override
   public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
       JdbcTransaction transaction = JdbcTransactionHolder.getCurrentTransaction();
       if(transaction != null) {
           // we get the connection from the transaction
           logger.debug("Transaction exists for the thread: {}.", Thread.currentThread());
           return transaction.getConnection();
       }
       Connection conn = this.dataSource.getConnection();
       conn.setAutoCommit(false);
       return conn;
   }

   @Override
   public Connection getConnection(String username, String password)
           throws SQLException {
       JdbcTransaction transaction = JdbcTransactionHolder.getCurrentTransaction();
       if(transaction != null) {
           // we get the connection from the transaction
           logger.debug("Transaction exists for the thread: {}.", Thread.currentThread());
           return transaction.getConnection();
       }

       return this.dataSource.getConnection(username, password);
   }
   ```

   }
4. then create a DataSourceProvider so that we can inject DataSource to any POJO using guice:

   public class DataSourceProvider implements Provider {

   ```
   private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataSourceProvider.class);

   private DataSource dataSource;


   public DataSourceProvider() {

       JdbcConfig config = getConfig();
       ComboPooledDataSource pooledDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

       try {
           pooledDataSource.setDriverClass(config.getDriver());
       } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }

       pooledDataSource.setJdbcUrl(config.getUrl());
       pooledDataSource.setUser(config.getUsername());
       pooledDataSource.setPassword(config.getPassword() );
       pooledDataSource.setMinPoolSize(config.getMinPoolSize());
       pooledDataSource.setAcquireIncrement(5);
       pooledDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(config.getMaxPoolSize());
       pooledDataSource.setMaxStatements(config.getMaxStatementSize());
       pooledDataSource.setAutoCommitOnClose(false);

       this.dataSource = new JdbcDataSource(pooledDataSource);
   }


   private JdbcConfig getConfig() {

       JdbcConfig config = new JdbcConfig();
       Properties prop = new Properties();
       try {
           //load a properties file from class path, inside static method
           prop.load(JdbcConfig.class.getResourceAsStream("/database.properties"));

           //get the property value and print it out
           config.setDriver(prop.getProperty("driver"));
           config.setUrl(prop.getProperty("url"));
           config.setUsername(prop.getProperty("username"));
           config.setPassword(prop.getProperty("password"));

           String maxPoolSize = prop.getProperty("maxPoolSize");
           if(maxPoolSize != null) {
               config.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(maxPoolSize));
           }

           String maxStatementSize = prop.getProperty("maxStatementSize");
           if(maxStatementSize != null) {
               config.setMaxStatementSize(Integer.parseInt(maxStatementSize));
           }

           String minPoolSize = prop.getProperty("minPoolSize");
           if(minPoolSize != null) {
               config.setMinPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(minPoolSize));
           }
       } 
       catch (Exception ex) {
           logger.error("Failed to load the config file!", ex);
           throw new DBException("Cannot read the config file: database.properties. Please make sure the file is present in classpath.", ex);
       }

       return config;
   }

   @Override
   public DataSource get() {
       return dataSource;
   }
   ```
5. and then implement TransactionalMethodInterceptor to manage the transaction for the method with Transactional annotation:

   public class TransactionalMethodInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

   ```
   private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TransactionalMethodInterceptor.class);

   @Inject
   private JdbcTransactionManager transactionManager;

   @Override
   public Object invoke(MethodInvocation method) throws Throwable {

       try {
           // Start the transaction
           transactionManager.begin();
           logger.debug("Start to invoke the method: " + method);

           Object result = method.proceed();
           logger.debug("Finish invoking the method: " + method);
           transactionManager.commit();
           return result;
       } catch (Exception e) {
           logger.error("Failed to commit transaction!", e);
           try {
               transactionManager.rollback();

           }
           catch(Exception ex) {
               logger.warn("Cannot roll back transaction!", ex);
           }
           throw e;
       }
   }
   ```

   }
6. Finally, the code to put all together so that Guice can inject the instances:

   ```
   bind(DataSource.class).toProvider(DataSourceProvider.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);

   bind(TransactionManager.class).to(JdbcTransactionManager.class);
   TransactionalMethodInterceptor transactionalMethodInterceptor = new TransactionalMethodInterceptor();
   requestInjection(transactionalMethodInterceptor);
   bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(Transactional.class), transactionalMethodInterceptor);


   bind(TestDao.class).to(JdbcTestDao.class);
   bind(TestService.class).to(TestServiceImpl.class);
   ```

I use c3p0 for the datasource pool. so, it works just fine in my test.

I find another related question: [Guice, JDBC and managing database connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347384/guice-jdbc-and-managing-database-connections)

but so far I haven't find any similar approach, except something in SpringFramework. but even the implementation in Spring seems quite complex.

I would like to ask if anyone has any suggestion for this solution.

thanks.

Comment: one thing in mind: instead of using RuntimeException, the exception needs to be defined specific to handle errors.